# replace similar but different parts of a string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, replace, echo

So I grab a string (usually an image location). Ideally, I would like it to always be

```
http://www.mydomain.com/images/cool-nifty-image.png
```

However, sometimes, it isn't always like that. sometimes it's

```
http://www.mydomain.com/images/cool-lame-image-300x300.png
```

with the 300x300 being relevant to the size. in the above example, I need the image located at

```
http://www.mydomain.com/images/cool-lame-image.png
```

(Yes, it ALWAYS exists.)

This would be easy it it was always triple digits. However, sometimes it can also be

```
    http://www.mydomain.com/images/cool-lame-image-300x99.png
```

or

```
    http://www.mydomain.com/images/cool-lame-image-99x99.png
```

Is there a way to find **" -#x#"** so I can find -100x99 and -875x200?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a regex for this task

```
$img = preg_replace('/-\d+x\d+(\.png)$/', '\1', $img);
```

Comment: Upvoted, thanks! It works perfectly! Will accept in 6 minutes :) - however, I don't know much about regex, thus can't decipher too much of that code... what if it's a jpg or a gif?

Comment: @AlexDemchak Then make the regex look like this: `/-\d+x\d+(\.(png|jpg|gif))$/i`. Added i so it's case insensitive (so that .PNG matches too).

Comment: @Robin - You probably want to make the inner grouping a non-capturing group: `/-\d+x\d+(\.(?:png|jpg|gif))$/i`

Comment: You could also just use `(\..+?)$` if the extension could be anything; then you don't need separate groups.

Comment: @ExplosionPills I wish I could give you more points for that. With a tweak or two, it turned out to work perfectly, exactly what I needed! Thanks! :)